# Bytes encoding in cryptography module giving error

Tags: python, string, cryptography, byte, python-cryptography

I am using the `cryptography` module's `Fernet` for encoding.
The Fernet technique converts the data to bytes using a key, and then we can convert the bytes back to a string using that same key.
I want to convert the encoded bytes to a string and store that string. (It is important for me to convert it to a string).

So, I used the following way:

```
f = Fernet(key)
mystr = str(f.encrypt(bytes(mystr, "utf-8")))        # convert mystr to bytes
```

But now, when I try to convert the string back to bytes, I am unable to decrypt it again.

```
mystr = str(f.decrypt(bytes(mystr, "utf-8")))        # convert mystr back to a string
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Python\Encode.py", line 155, in encode
    data = str(f.decrypt(bytes(data, "utf-8")))
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 75, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 107, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

I tried decrypting like:

```
mystr = str(f.decrypt(bytes(mystr, "ascii")))
```

or

```
mystr = str(f.decrypt(bytes(mystr, "base64")))
```

but, the error is still present.

Comment: did you use `print()` to see what you have in variables ? Probably you should see prefix `b` when you use `str()` to convert bytes - and this can make problem. You should use `string_data.encode('utf-8')`, `bytes_data.decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `print()` to see what you have in variables after using `bytes` and `str()

When you use

```
 bytes('abc', 'utf-8')
```

then you get

```
 b'abc'
```

and when you use

```
 str(b'abc')
```

then you get

```
 "b'abc'"
```

instead of `'abc'` - and this prefix `b` and `' '` change everything. Now you have string with 6 chars instead of 3 chars.

You should use `encode` to create `bytes` and `decode` to create `string` again

```
  'abc'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```